# Accessing a controller function via link

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to understand how our Yii2 website works, and one problem I have is that we have the functions actionXml() and actionXml2() in our SomemodelController. actionXml() can be called via

> [https://our.site.com/somemodel/xml?AccessControl[SecurityToken]=somesecuritytoken](https://our.site.com/somemodel/xml?AccessControl%5BSecurityToken%5D=somesecuritytoken)

However, I don't know how actionXml2 can be accessed and I'm trying to find out how to get there. I tried changing the link to

> [https://our.site.com/somemodel/xml2?AccessControl[SecurityToken]=somesecuritytoken](https://our.site.com/somemodel/xml2?AccessControl%5BSecurityToken%5D=somesecuritytoken)

or changing the securitytoken in the code (both use the exact same security token in the code), which both just lead to a blank page saying access denied. How do I actually construct an url that leads to the proper function in the controller?

On our filesystem under somemodel/xml.php, there is some code, of which none calls actionXml(), so I just copied that into xml2.php. How do I now link that to actionXml2()?

Answer (score 0):

A Controller/action is "automatically   called  by yii2 routing routing component

You should check in the controller

```
   somemodelController
```

and take a look at

```
   actionXml()
```

this is based on

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-workflow
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-overview

and so on ....